# Python IndexError: string index out of range error

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is open a file, read the first line (which is a number), add one to that number, and replace the first line with that number. However, I get a string index out of range error. My code is:

```
f = open("testfile.txt","r")
line = f.readline()
x = line[1]

x +=1

f = open("testfile.txt","w")
f.write(x) 
f.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: why `line[1]` what about the first element? (post the input file)

Comment: `line[0]` is the first line, not `line[1]`.

Comment: `line[0]` is the first *character* of the first line.

Comment: Thanks @SethMMorton, however when I use line[0] instead I get an error stating (TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly). So, I tried converting it into a string by using str(x), however I get the same error.

Comment: What do you expect `x += 1` to do?  I'll guess that is the line it is telling you the error is on.

Comment: @SethMMorton I am expecting x +=1 to add one to the x integer.

Comment: @user2419553 The characters of a file are strings, you must cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = int(line[0]) # cast the first character at index 0 to an int, shouldn't be a string
```